# can't word with built-in marcos with doucments4j

Tags: ms-word, converters, documents4j

I'm currently using documents4j to convert doc/docx files to pdf files. It works great! Thanks for the team!

But there is one problems: when I tried to convert some word files with built-in Macro, the convert will just failed.

I tried to do some debugging with the generated VB script, it seems after open the file, the call to ExportAsFixedFormat fails. Even the call to wordDocument.Close fails either.

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you see the Word application, is it visible? It's possible Word's security is blocking opening the document because it's set to not allow macros?

Answer (score 0):

documents4j does not execute macros as those can be interactive whereas documents4j runs in a headless mode where such interactions are not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I need is not to run the macros in the document. The only thing I need is to make the files with macros to be converted to pdf files. But the problem is when I use documents4j to convert such files, the call to ExportAsFixedFormat will in the VBS.

Comment: You can try to edit the VBS script and to put a modified version into a jar at the beginning of the class path. documents4j will use that script then.